# How to prevent PHP Post Max Size being exceeded on a Form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a FORM on a PHP web page that accepts a table of data (editable-grid) which the end-user is in control of in that they can add as many rows as they like. One of the fields is also a TEXTAREA which means each row has a variable size.

If the post is too large however, it will be rejected by the server and all the target page will see is an empty $_POST. Worse, if the user navigates back to the input page, it will show its initial empty state, losing all data entered and annoying the end-user to say the least.

I could increase the POST_max_size setting in PHP, but all that will do is push the boundary at which it will fail.

I could also check in JavaScript what the size of the post will be, PRIOR to them submitting the form, ideally as they add each row or change the textarea content, but I'm not sure how accurate or slow that will be. It also means they would have to remove some data or rows.

The only other option I can think of is to submit each row individually in a hidden FORM, through AJAX, once they click the Submit button. I'm not sure it is a good idea to replace one post with hundreds of posts to the server.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/webismymind/editablegrid.git?

Comment: No, I have built my own js library. No other libraries involved, just straight HTML + PHP + JS.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending the entire datagrid you can **just send the edited row** as if it were a single form using javascript. If you send each row in a loop with ajax even if it is not edited you can choke the server in the same way as if you were sending the entire datagrid. Instead of sending 20k rows of data with just one column modified, just send one row when the user leaves the textarea.

I don't know how you manage the editing events but with jQuery (for the sake of simplicity) could be something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea, input').on('blur', function(e) {
       var $row = $(this).closest('tr')
       var data = { 
           id: $row.data('id'),
           input: $row.find('td input').val(),
           textarea: $row.find('td textarea').val()
       };

       // e.g. foo.php/1 
       $.post("foo.php/" + data.id, data)
        .success(function() { /* silent success */ })
        .fail(function() { alert('Error') })
    });
});
```

with html

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-id="1">
            <td><input /></td>
            <td><textarea></textarea></td>
        </tr>
         <tr data-id="2">
            <td><input /></td>
            <td><textarea></textarea></td>
        </tr>
         <tr data-id="3">
            <td><input /></td>
            <td><textarea></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

example jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vt0a0udx

ps: sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Thanks absalon.valdes, that is what I thought of too. Your English is fine, I understood what you wrote easily. I was hoping for some other ideas though. 

There is a lot more to it using AJAX since I have to give feedback on number of calls outstanding, number of rows that have failed and indicate which ones, prevent navigation away until all updates are returned, update inserted rows with the auto-increment ID etc, etc. I'm busy with that now, but was hoping there would be an easier way to do this. Ah well, I guess I just should not be lazy!

Comment: As far as server-load goes, I was thinking the overhead of each Ajax call would make it slower, but not too much bandwidth overhead I think. When submitting as a single form, I had some optimization code that removed unchanged rows just sending those that were added, changed or marked for delete.  This is for an accounting application capturing posting transactions, so potentially could have hundreds of rows to submit per page.

Comment: The entire table is built dynamically on page load with my own JS library, no jQuery at all. It caters for insertion of rows, calculation of totals on bottom row, sorting by column, code lookups (more AJAX). So it is not too much work to integrate the submission loop.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1):

try to change this value in php.ini

> max_input_vars = 1000 to 10000

Comment: I have used that setting, but the trouble is if the total size of the POST in bytes is too large, it doesn't even get that far - the $_POST is just empty.